# All of the drop-down boxes have stopped working

Tags: support

I can no longer click on the arrow by name to get the drop down box to appear. I can no longer comment or vote. I think an update broke something on the stack exchange website. I tried the askubuntu site as well. That has the same issue.

FF 6.0.2 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: I also use FF 6.0.2 on Ubuntu 11.04 and it works alright.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a problem with your browser cache. Clear your browser cache and try again.

(Also, Firefox 7 was just released, I think.)

Comment: That fixed it. (FF 7 has filtered down into ubuntu repos yet, I don't think...)

Comment: Firefox 7 is in the beta update channel for Ubuntu 11.04 and will be the default for 11.10.